# Data Annotations ValidationException was unhandled by user Code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, data-annotations

I have been working my way through Brian Noyes' excellent pluralsight course on wpf data binding, and have hit an issue with data annotations.

I began by downloading his `c#` sample and running it and saw exactly what I expected to see and had seen him demonstrate in the course.  Then I set about implementing the same in my own project (but in this case in `vb` as opposed to `c#`).  I'm using entity `Framework`.

I created an `EntityBase Class` as suggested like so;

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class EntityBase
    Protected Overridable Sub ValidateProperty(ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal value As Object)
            Dim context As New ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing)
            context.MemberName = propertyName
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value, context)
        End Sub
End Class
```

I inherit this base class on my entity and then in one of the properties of the entity set up a data annotation and call the base `ValidateProperty` method.

```
    <System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(6)> _
    Public Overridable Property VesselPlnLetterPart() As String
        Get
            Return _VesselPlnLetterPart
        End Get
        Set
            If (Object.Equals(_VesselPlnLetterPart, value) = false) Then
              Me.OnVesselPlnLetterPartChanging(value)
              OnPropertyChanging("VesselPlnLetterPart")
              _VesselPlnLetterPart = value
                ValidateProperty("VesselPlnLetterPart",value)
              Me.OnVesselPlnLetterPartChanged()
              OnPropertyChanged("VesselPlnLetterPart")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _VesselPlnLetterPart As String
```

Finally in the `Xaml` I bind to this property and set `ValidateOnExceptions= true`.

```
  <TextBox Margin="5" Width="50" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" CharacterCasing="Upper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=VesselPlnLetterPart, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

All exactly as done in his demo and sample, but when I run this it breaks on the last line of the ValidateProperty method telling me that I have a ValidationException that was unhandled by user code (because I have deliberately passed a string that is too long the inner detail is telling me that it exceeds the permitted length.)  What vital bit have I missed when it comes to handling this though?

Has anyone encountered this when trying to use data annotations and can give me a clue as to why this is occurring?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the visual studio debugger, if you run this without the debugger or you continue after the exception is thrown it should validate as expected.

If this is a problem you could consider using IDataErrorInfo instead of exceptions for the validation. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349050/datavalidation-in-wpf-using-validatesonexceptions) to the same answer for a different option involving a custom exception.